# Индексы в join запросах

Tags: mysql

Смотрю выполнение запроса через **EXPLAIN** :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT gs.san,ean.ean_code,gs.name,oe.quantity FROM goods gs LEFT JOIN order_elements oe ON gs.san=oe.san LEFT JOIN ean ON ean.good_id=gs.id WHERE oe.order_id=42
```

[image: Результат запроса]

Как видно индекс '*san*' не работает. Почему? В запросах типа `SELECT * FROM goods WHERE san='xxxx';` Индекс работает

Comment: Надо начать с того, что запрос в принципе не корректен. Если у вас жесткое условие на таблицу oe в where, то значит в этой таблице в любом случае должны быть подходящие записи, а это совершенно не согласуется со словом LEFT в join этой таблицы, которое говорит что наличие подходящих записей в этой таблице не обязательно. А наличие не работающих left может сбивать с толку оптимизатор

Comment: кроме того судя по плану выполнения у вас в таблицах слишком мало записей. после того как во всех трех таблицах будет хотя бы по несколько тысяч записей можно начинать смотреть планы выполнения. Пока таблицы слишком малы MySQL вообще не будет использовать индексы, потому что работа по ним будет дольше, чем полный перебор таких таблиц